# Injectivness of a composition of Linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Prove or Disprove the following:

> Let $L: U\rightarrow V$ and $M: V\rightarrow W$ be linear mappings, if
>   $M\circ L$ is injective:
>
> 1. L is injective
> 2. M is injective

Let $x$ be a vector in $U$.
Since $M\circ L$ is injective, $M\circ L(x) = 0$ implies $L(x) = 0$ so $M$ being injective is fairly obvious, but it seems like $L$ being injective is not necessarily true, but I can't come up with a counterexample. Am I wrong about 2)? Any help for 1)?

Comment: If $L$ is not injective, there is $x\in V$  such that $x\neq 0$  and $L(x)=0$.  So $M \circ L(X)=0$, so $M\circ L$ is not injective.

Comment: On the other hand, your argument regarding $M$ only proves that $M$ is injective when restricted to the image of $L$. In fact, It the best we can prove about $M$. $M$ don't need to be injective from $V$ to $W$. 


Example: Let $L: \mathbb{R^2}\to   \mathbb{R^3}$  be defined as $L((x,y))=(x,y,0)$ and $M: \mathbb{R^3}\to   \mathbb{R^2}$  be defined as $M((x,y,z))=(x,y)$.  It is clear that $M\circ L$ is the identity in $ \mathbb{R^2}$ and so is injective.  It is easy to see that $M$ is NOT injective. $M$ is injective only when restricted to the image of $L$.